# Is linear projection an identify map?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a linear projection A $\in$ $\mathbb{L}$(X) such that A$^2$ = A. Then, we have A$^2$(x) = AA(x) = A(A(x)) = A(x), can we have A(x) = x from the last equality?

Comment: No, we can't. Why should we? $A$ is not usually invertible.

Comment: $A=0$ is a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: $A$ is the identity on the *image set*, that can be as small as... $\{0\}$ (cf, @KaviRamaMurthy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're essentially claiming that $A^2=A$ implies $A$ is the identity $I$.

This is false. Writing it as $0=A^2-A=A(A-I)$, this just implies that the range of $A-I$ is contained in the kernel of $A$.

A simple counterexample is with $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, with basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $A$ the linear map determined by $A(e_1)=e_1$, $A(e_2)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

What is a projection?

Suppose we have some space $U$, and a subspace $V.$

$A$ maps vectors in $U$ onto $V,$ but it doesn't do anything to vectors in $V.$

Every vector in $U$, can be described as a combination of $k + v$ where $k$ is in the kernel of $U$ and $v$ is in $V$ and $A(k+v) = A(k) + A(v) = A(v) = v$